# Spring validation JSR-303 @NotNull throw NotReadablePropertyException

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have two classes

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SearchProductOffer {
    @Valid
    private List<MatchProperty> properties = new ArrayList<>();
}
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MatchProperty {
    private String version;
    private String sourceSystem;
    @NotNull(message = "Версия должна быть заполнена!")
    public String codeName;
}
```

while i validate A with ValidationUtil.invokeValidator i get

> 2018-07-06 16:04:09.769 ERROR 10223 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property
>   'properties[1].codeName' does not have a corresponding accessor for
>   Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean
>   property versus direct field access)] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'properties[1]' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean
>   property 'properties[1]' is not readable or has an invalid getter
>   method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of
>   the setter?   at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

when fieldB is null. Both classes have getter/setter.
Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

UPDATE
I get exception every time, while i want validate with @NotNull(while field value is null) or @NotEmpty(while my field is "") field in inner class.

Comment: Are the getter and setters are public?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to have anything to do with your code. Post real code that reproduces the issue, with the real and complete exception stack trace.

Comment: i use lombok @Data and in *.class files i saw getters and setters

Comment: I would say the problem is not validation but incorrect path in your HTML. Looks that you use `properties[1]` somewhere in your path. Please post the JSP you use

Comment: I use jackson objectMapper to get object from json. After deserialize i get normal java object and some fields has null value. Field with null value annotated with @NotNull (codeName). I call SmartValidator.validate and then i get exception. I validate full valid java object and SmartValidator.validate must create FieldError from codeName field, but it throw exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: remove spring **SmartValidator**. 
Configure binder in controller

```
@InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.initDirectFieldAccess();
    }
```

Configure validator in boot config

```
@Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

And inject it into controller

```
@Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
```

after it we can call

```
List<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validationResult = new ArrayList<>();
validationResult.addAll(validator.validate(request));   
validationResult.addAll(validator.validate(methodBean));
```

and check **validationResult** for validation errors